# shrink my png with alpha channel

Tags: compression, alpha-transparency

First off, I'm not a graphics programmer and I probably don't know the right terminology for what I want to do.  I have an idea of what I want to do but I'm not finding out how.  I will try to describe what I want but keep in mind I might be using terminology incorrectly.  And maybe there is a better way to do what I want than what I think I need to do.

My main goal is:  I have a picture about 250000 bytes in size and I'd like to make the file size smaller.

Note that the original picture is full brightness, but I have used the gimp (probably incorrectly) to make it have a faded appearance.  I think it now has an "alpha channel" with some opacity percentage value.  So I think the picture is stored as full brightness in the rgb channels and there is another alpha channel describing the "fadedness" of the picture.  The image should fade to "white" - it will be placed on a white background and will have dark text on it - but I don't think I have stored that last bit of info in the image (yet).

So here's how I'm trying to get there:  I figure the picture could be smaller if I just specify the actual pixel value of the faded picture in the rgb channels and do away with the alpha channel.  Also there should be fewer colours overall and I could use a colour map, making the picture even smaller.  The faded picture is faded enough that text is legible when written across it - i.e. it's quite faded - so there should be a lot fewer colours than the full-brightness version.

However I don't know how to do that, or what to look for in the documentation.  I've tried a few "compression" programs and the best compression I got was about 2.5%.  Obviously I'm not looking in the right places because I think it should compress to a lot smaller than that.

Here is the imagemagick "identify -verbose" output:

```
bjb@rhino:~/work/mojatatu/admin/2015/web/foo/img/work$ identify -verbose ../orig/joanrobins-penguins-snow-banner-faded.png 
Image: ../orig/joanrobins-penguins-snow-banner-faded.png
  Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 799x152+0+0
  Resolution: 137.8x137.8
  Print size: 5.79826x1.10305
  Units: PixelsPerCentimeter
  Type: TrueColorAlpha
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
    alpha: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Red:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 145.053 (0.568837)
      standard deviation: 51.0466 (0.200183)
      kurtosis: 0.897068
      skewness: -1.18367
    Green:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 253 (0.992157)
      mean: 152.236 (0.597003)
      standard deviation: 53.6199 (0.210274)
      kurtosis: 0.941151
      skewness: -1.2307
    Blue:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 251 (0.984314)
      mean: 164.608 (0.645521)
      standard deviation: 56.552 (0.221772)
      kurtosis: 1.13143
      skewness: -1.37866
    Alpha:
      min: 84 (0.329412)
      max: 84 (0.329412)
      mean: 84 (0.329412)
      standard deviation: 0 (0)
      kurtosis: 0
      skewness: 0
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 158.224 (0.620487)
      standard deviation: 46.5805 (0.182669)
      kurtosis: 2.94443
      skewness: -1.70687
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Interlace: None
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgba(223,223,223,1)
  Matte color: grey74
  Transparent color: none
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 799x152+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: Zip
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    date:create: 2015-03-21T19:32:58-04:00
    date:modify: 2015-03-21T19:32:58-04:00
    png:bKGD                 : chunk was found (see Background color, above)
    png:cHRM                 : chunk was found (see Chromaticity, above)
    png:gAMA                 : gamma=0.45454544 (See Gamma, above)
    png:IHDR.bit_depth       : 8
    png:IHDR.color_type      : 6 (RGBA)
    png:IHDR.interlace_method: 0 (Not interlaced)
    png:IHDR.width,height    : 799, 152
    png:pHYs                 : x_res=13780, y_res=13780, units=1
    png:sRGB                 : intent=0 (See Rendering intent)
    signature: 6ceec80b4c3c05a631de400d74928ca4cb86bd9f304676ecd4a475b874a71cfc
  Artifacts:
    filename: ../orig/joanrobins-penguins-snow-banner-faded.png
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 248KB
  Number pixels: 121K
  Pixels per second: 0B
  User time: 0.000u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.000
  Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-03-08 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

I've looked at some of the ImageMagick documentation and tried most of the following tools (I also had to shrink a .jpg and found that jpegoptim worked well).

```
  Setting up advancecomp (1.15-1) ...       advpng -z4 file.png.  didn't see any compression
  Setting up jpegoptim (1.2.3-2+b2) ...     two thumbs up - easy and effective
  Setting up optipng (0.6.4-1) ...
  Setting up pngcrush (1.7.9-1) ...
  Setting up pngnq (1.0-2) ...
  Setting up pngquant (1.0-4.1) ...
  Setting up trimage (1.0.5-1) ...


  imagemagic convert

  convert
    -clut (apply a color lookup table to the image)
    -hald-clut
    -unique-colors
    -quantize colorspace  <- reduce colors in this colorspace
    -posterize levels  <- reduce  the image to a limited number of color levels
    -modulate value  <- vary the brightness, saturation, and hue
    -layers method       optimize or compare image layers
    -fuzz distance       colors within this distance are considered equal

    -depth value         image depth


    -alpha remove
  on, activate, off, deactivate, set, opaque, copy", transparent, extract, background, or shape the alpha channel
    -background  white


    - colors value   preferred number of colors in the image
    - colorspace type   set image colorspace
```

I've also tried converting the picture to a jpg and back to png in the hopes that it would do what I want but it saved the full-brightness version as jpg and back again as png, probably lost the alpha channel info.

`pngcrush -brute` tries over 100 compression techniques and selects the best one, that was the one that gave about 2.5% best compression.  But, surely this picture can be compressed more than that, given I am perfectly willing to lose information (not interested in keeping the original brightness info)?

Comment: Mmmmm... your alpha channel (transparency) does not appear to *fade* anywhere as you describe - it is a constant 84 across your image. It would help if you could post your image.

Comment: You are correct and I seem to be using the term "fade" incorrectly. The picture has an alpha of 84 across the image and that is the effect I wanted. I was trying to describe that in English but I guess "fade" is commonly used for "gradient-of-transparency" while I was using it for "constant-washed-out appearance". The picture is at https://netdev01.org/static/img/joanrobins-penguins-snow-banner-faded.png.

Comment: I had a tough time choosing between Glenn's and Mark's answers ... Mark got the size down the most, but Glenn most directly answered my question.  In the end I used Glenn's answer, but tacked on Mark's option -color 256 to get the file size down a lot further.

Comment: I'm more than happy to come second to a *top chap* like Glenn, and glad we could help you out :-)

Comment: @BrendaJ.Butler, frequently it's better to use -colors 255 instead of 256, to leave room for the background color in the palette.  I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compose your transparent image against the white background from the png bKGD chunk, using the alpha channel that you created, you can do

```
convert rgba.png -flatten -alpha off rgb-flattened.png
```

Then to optimize the compression and remove some ancillary chunks that
ImageMagick inserts,

```
pngcrush -reduce -brute -rem alla rgb-flattened.png rgb.png
```

Note that the order of the options "-alpha off" and "-flatten" is important.
If you put "-alpha off" first, the alpha channel won't be used in the flattening process and you'll end up with the original unfaded image.

EDIT: For further optimization, use the -colors 255 to reduce the image from RGBA-PNG to indexed-PNG:

```
convert rgba.png -flatten -alpha off -colors 255 indexed-flattened.png
pngcrush -reduce -brute -rem alla indexed-flattened.png indexed.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure what you really want, but maybe this will get you headed in the right direction. If you want a "*washed out look*", you can typically achieve that by either reducing the contrast of an image - so that blacks become more grey than black and whites become more grey than white, or by reducing the saturation which decreases the colour intensity making the picture less vivid or tending more to black and white.

So, you can do the following to discard the alpha channel (transparency) and decrease the contrast and reduce the number of colours in the image. The file size goes down from 250kB to 62kB - but it may not be what you seek...

```
convert yourPengy.png -alpha off +level 65%,95% -colors 256 myPengy.png
```

[image]

Or maybe this is closer to what you want, with the saturation decreased to 80%, at 62kB

```
convert yourPengy.png -alpha off -modulate 100,80 +level 55%,95% -colors 256 myPengy.png
```

[image]